# Submit a text string plus file - edited

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to submit a text string (downloadstr) and 1 second later to submit a file.
I have to do this in plain JS/HTML (microcontroller webserver)

I submit the text using 'GET' to avoid the 'name=' in the string.
I submit the file using POST.
I need to access the file locally first to get the file size which is needed in the text string.

I can get it partially working - BUT
I cannot seem to change the <input id="DN" .value to the variable 'downloadstr' in JS.

NOTE ***** - There seems to be a problem with the JS variable 'downloadstr'.
I can give it any sort of textual value and it will upload fine, but the string '   LOAD(NAND,"EXT/tu480a.ppf?size=641&useack=1");  ' will upload a corrupted string. I cannot see what is wrong with this string.
It displays correctly, but will not upload.
This is the string that it tries to upload:

LOAD                           NAND �          2.186360E-77XT0.000000tu480a.ppf0.000000size134219621641                2779096485seack6039898721                     %29  B

---

Can some kind person tell me whats wrong? Thanks. Chris
(I've updated via the comments - thanks)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 

 <form id="predataform" method="get" action="/index.shtml" accept-charset="utf-8">

  <input id="DN" type="hidden" name="DNDATA" value="xxx">
  <script>
   console.log("downloadstr");
  </script>
 </form>

 <form id="uploadform" action="/index.shtml" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <p>Please specify a ppt file to upload :
   <br>
   <input type="file" name="datafilemnu" size="40" onchange="checkFile()">
   <input type="button" value="UPLOAD" name="dnip" onclick="submitboth()">
  </p>
 </form>
 <div>
  <p id="downstring"></p>
  <p id="fsize"></p>

 </div>

 <script>

var downloadstr = "";

document.getElementById("DN").value = downloadstr;
function checkFile() {
 var sFileName = "";
 var sFileExtension = "";
 var iFileSize = 0;
 var iConvert = "";
 var node = "";
 var node_list = document.getElementsByName("datafilemnu");
 for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
  node = node_list[i];
  if (node.getAttribute("type") == "file" && node.files.length > 0) {
   console.log(node.files[0]);
   sFileName = node.value;
   sFileExtension = sFileName.split(".")[sFileName.split(".").length - 1];
   iFileSize = node.files[0].size;
   iConvert = node.files[0].size.toFixed(0);
  }
  if (sFileExtension == "ppf" && iFileSize > 0) {
   document.getElementById("fsize").innerHTML =
    "Size=" +
    iConvert +
    " bytes. Estimated time to download = " +
    ((iConvert * 10) / 115200 / 60).toFixed(1) +
    " minutes ";
   downloadstr =
    'LOAD(NAND,"EXT/' +
    node.files.item(0).name +
    '?size=' +
    iFileSize +
    '&useack=1")';
   document.getElementById("downstring").innerHTML = downloadstr;
   document.getElementById("DN").value = downloadstr;
   console.log(downloadstr);
  }
 }
}

function submitboth() {
 document.getElementById("predataform").submit();

 setTimeout(function () {
  document.getElementById("uploadform").submit();
   window.location.reload();
 }, 1000);
 
}


 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById` in 2 places...

Comment: what's with the window.location.reload() ? that'll fire before your timeout gets a chance to run?

Comment: Thanks ever so much ! I'm so exhausted  looking at it I didnt notice!

Comment: I've changed the document.getElementById 's and placed the    window.location.reload(); inside the function()
However, its still not working. The download to server file was working so I must be close! Unfortunately I cant revert my code.

Comment: Please update your original post to reflect your changes. It's easier for others to follow what it going on and help provide a solution.

Comment: have updated code

Comment: You can not submit a form and then submit another one on the same page. The form reloads the page. If you need to do this, you are either doing to have to make the forms target another page or an iframe. OR use Ajax/fetch

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.
I have found the answer to the main problem of corruption.
The webserver itself was converting the '(' to %28 - hex value (and some of the other characters) for some reason when it was being received.
I will have to check the webserver code. Sorry to cause so much confusion!
However, I have learnt to watch out for miss-spelling in my javascript!!